# Using two different rows from the same table in an expression

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL + PostGIS.

In table I have a point and line geometry in the same column of the same table, in different rows. To get the line I run:

```
SELECT the_geom
FROM filedata
WHERE id=3
```

If i want to take point I run:

```
SELECT the_geom
FROM filedata
WHERE id=4
```

I want take point and line together, like they're shown in this WITH expression, but using a real query against the table instead:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT 'LINESTRING (50 40, 40 60, 50 90, 30 140)'::geometry AS road,
       'POINT (60 110)'::geometry AS poi)

SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(road, ST_Line_Locate_Point(road, poi))) AS projected_poi

FROM data;
```

You see in this example data comes from a hand-created WITH expression. I want take it from my `filedata` table. My problem is i dont know how to work with data from two different rows of one table at the same time.

Comment: Deleted my answer, you just completely changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: Sorry i was express  my thoughts uncorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(fd_road.the_geom, ST_Line_Locate_Point(
      fd_road.the_geom,
      fd_poi.the_geom
  )) AS projected_poi
FROM filedata fd_road, filedata fd_poi
WHERE fd_road.id = 3 AND fd_poi.id = 4;
```

Alternately use a subquery to fetch the other row, as Erwin pointed out.

The main options for using multiple rows from one table in a single expression are:

- Self-join the table with two different aliases as shown above, then filter the rows;
- Use a subquery expression to get a value for all but one of the rows, as Erwin's answer shows;
- Use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) like `lag()` and `lead()` to get a row relative to the current row within the query result; or
- `JOIN` on a subquery that returns a table

The latter two are more advanced options that solve problems that're difficult or inefficient to solve with the simpler self-join or subquery expression.

Comment: i can replace `road` to `(SELECT the_geom FROM filedata WHERE id=3)` or i gonna do like in @Erwin Brandstetter answer?

Comment: @KliverMax Whoops, I didn't notice that. Erwin's answer avoids an extra subquery, so it's a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way:
A subquery to retrieve another value from a different row.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
          ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(
             the_geom
            ,ST_Line_Locate_Point(
                the_geom
               ,(SELECT the_geom FROM filedata WHERE id = 4)
             )
          )
       ) AS projected_poi
FROM   filedata
WHERE  id = 3;
```